# Python - threading assert group is None when creating a custom Thread Class

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I wanted to create a custom Thread class that is able to propagate an exception it comes across to the main thread. My implementation is as follows:

```py
class VerseThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, args):
        super().__init__(self, args=args)
        # self.scraper = scraper

    def run(self):
        self.exc = None
        try:
            book, abbrev, template, chapter = self.args
            self.parser.parse(book, abbrev, template, chapter)
        except ChapterNotFoundError as e:
            self.exc = e

    def join(self):
        threading.Thread.join(self)
        if self.exc:
            raise self.exc
```

This is supposed to run in the following method, inside a Scraper class (it's all inside a `ẁhile true`):

```py
for book, abbrev, testament in self.books[init:end]:
    base_chapter = 1
    while True:
        threads = []
        if testament == 'ot':
            for i in range(3):
                threads.append(VerseThread(args=(book, abbrev, OT_TEMPLATE, base_chapter+i)))
        else:
            for i in range(3):
                threads.append(VerseThread(args=(book, abbrev, NT_TEMPLATE, base_chapter+i)))
                            
        try:
            for thread in threads:
                if not thread.is_alive():
                    thread.start()
            for thread in threads:
                thread.join()
            base_chapter += 3
        except ChapterNotFoundError as e:
            LOGGER.info(f"{{PROCESS {multiprocessing.current_process().pid}}} - Chapter {e.chapter} not found in {book}, exiting book...")
            break
```

The issue is, if I run it like presented here, I get the error `assert group is None, "group argument must be None for now"`. However, when I run it using `Thread(target=self.parse, args=(book, abbrev, OT_TEMPLATE, base_chapter+1))` instead of `VerseThread(args=(book, abbrev, OT_TEMPLATE, base_chapter+i))`, it works just fine, but the exception is of course still there. What's wrong with my code? How can I get rid of this error?

**EDIT**: Upon further testing, it seems that what I'm trying to do works fine when I use `thread.run()` instead of `thread.start()`, but then only one thread is being used, which is a problem. This, however, means that the error must be in the `start()` method, but I've no idea what to do.

Comment: Your `VerseThread` constructor appears to take two args (not counting `self`). They are `target`, and `args`. But at the call site, you only appear to provide a single argument, `args=(...)`. Not a Python expert here, so IDK how that's supposed to work.

Comment: I actually just forgot to that that out (thanks for pointing out), but the result is the same - still getting an error. But now that you mentioned it, I'll test it again

Comment: OK, But if the code that you are testing no longer is the same as the example shown in your question, then please bring the example up-to-date.

Comment: I just made the changes you pointed out - actually providing a target to the constructor of VerseThread. The error was the same. I'll update the example with the code I'm currently running.
Note that: this works with the `run()` method instead of `start()`, but then only one thread is used, so the error lies in that method.

Comment: You're not supposed to pass `self` explicitly to `super().anything()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors. First, if you are using `super()` as in `super().__init__(self, target=target, args=args)`, you do not pass *self* explicitly as an argument. Second, to handle any possible thread-initializer arguments, your signature for this method should just be as follows:

```py
class VerseThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    ... # rest of the code omitted
```

But since your `__init__` method does not do anything but call the parent's `__init__` method with any passed arguments, there is now no need to even override this method.

Finally, the attributes that you are interested in are not *args* but rather *_args* and *_kwargs* (in case keyword arguments are specified). Also, you have specified `self.parser`, but I do not see where that attribute has been set.

```py
import threading

class ChapterNotFoundError(Exception):
    pass

class VerseThread(threading.Thread):

    def run(self):
        self.exc = None
        try:
            book, abbrev, template, chapter = self._args
            self.parser.parse(book, abbrev, template, chapter)
        except ChapterNotFoundError as e:
            self.exc = e

    def join(self):
        threading.Thread.join(self)  # Or: super().join()
        if self.exc:
            raise self.exc

for book, abbrev, testament in self.books[init:end]:
    base_chapter = 1
    while True:
        threads = []
        if testament == 'ot':
            for i in range(3):
                threads.append(VerseThread(args=(book, abbrev, OT_TEMPLATE, base_chapter+i)))
        else:
            for i in range(3):
                threads.append(VerseThread(args=(book, abbrev, NT_TEMPLATE, base_chapter+i)))
                            
        try:
            for thread in threads:
                if not thread.is_alive():
                    thread.start()
            for thread in threads:
                thread.join()
            base_chapter += 3
        except ChapterNotFoundError as e:
            LOGGER.info(f"{{PROCESS {multiprocessing.current_process().pid}}} - Chapter {e.chapter} not found in {book}, exiting book...")
            break
```

**Improvement**

Accessing quasi-private attributes, such as `self._args` is a potentially dangerous thing and should be avoided.

I can see the value of creating a subclass of `Thread` that will catch exceptions in the "worker" function it is to execute and then "propogate" it back to the main thread when it joins the thread. But I believe such a class should be general purpose and work with any type of worker function. In general, I don't like to have application-specific code (business logic) in a `multithreading.Thread` or `multiprocessing.Pool` subclass. I instead prefer having my business logic coded within a function or class method(s) that can then be used in multithreading, multiprocessing or serial processing as you see fit. The following is how I would code the `Thread` subclass (I have named it `PropogateExceptionThread`, but chose whatever name you wish) and I might use it:

```py
import threading

class PropogateExceptionThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        self.exc = None
        try:
            super().run()
        except Exception as e:
            self.exc = e

    def join(self):
        super().join()
        if self.exc:
            raise self.exc

def worker(x):
    if x < 10 or x > 20:
        raise ValueError(f'Bad value for argument x = {x}')

t = PropogateExceptionThread(target=worker, args=(1,))
t.start()
try:
    t.join()
except Exception as e:
    print('The thread raised an exception:', e)
```

Prints:

```None
The thread raised an exception: Bad value for argument x = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly. About the parser attribute -- I was passing a parser object in the constructor but forgot to change it over there. I agree, this type of class should be general-purpose, which is something I'll keep in mind from now on.